# execlp gives abort trap 6

Tags: c, system, call

When i execute the following code and give the arguments as "ls - l" , i get the abort trap :6 and the program exits.But when i just give ls as input the program works fine.Why is that happening.

Here :act_arg contains the string "ls" "-l"

```
 void function_run()
    {
        char bar[100] = "/bin/";
        char f_arg[100];
        int baz;
        int qux = 1;
        strncat(bar,act_arg[0],sizeof(act_arg[0]));
        while(act_arg[qux] != NULL)
        {
            strncat(f_arg,act_arg[qux] ,sizeof(act_arg[qux]));
        }

        //execute
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            baz = execlp(bar,act_arg[0],act_arg[1],NULL);
            if(baz == -1)
            {
                eng_run();      //to run execlp from normal lang run
                //wait(NULL);
            }
            else
            {
                //wait(NULL);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        fflush(stdout);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong :

```
if(fork() == 0)
{
    baz = execlp(bar,act_arg[0],act_arg[1],NULL);
    if(baz == -1)
    {
```

You need to send to execlp all arguments including "ls" so :

```
if(fork() == 0)
{
    baz = execlp(bar,act_arg[0],act_arg[0],NULL);
    if(baz == -1)
    {
```

Or by the way :

```
if(fork() == 0)
{
    baz = execve(act_arg[0], &act_arg[1]); //&act_arg[0] I don't remember
    if(baz == -1)
    {
```

Comment: It doesnt work with both the cases and execve should have 3 arguments not 2